# Re position an image with media queries

Tags: html, css

I have an image that is floated right full screen and comes below the main content. However, on mobile I want the image to be above the content and not below. Take into consideration that in my HTML the image is listed below the main content. **Any** suggestions would be amazing.

**Html Code**

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="main">
Main stuff 
</div>
<img src="image.jpg>
<div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use "display:flex" for the parent div which wraps your image and your text. And the property "order" for your child elements. If you want to switch the position of the element, you can change order depending on media queries.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items